# SPOJ D-Query , BIT but how?

Tags: algorithm, bit-manipulation, fenwick-tree

I am trying to solve D-query problem on Spoj. http://www.spoj.com/problems/DQUERY/ 
I am thinking about set and memorizing the result but that is really slow. So I was thinking about that Binary Indexed tree could help me to get lgN for one query but I can't think the solution with it. Can anyone help me.

Comment: You should summarize the problem statement in the question itself, don't just link to it.

Comment: How can I solve this problem using BIT?